# HttpWebRequest getting time out issue

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

I have a function UpdateCRM() which will make http web request to my CRM server to update data.
If it calling once it working fine. But when we calling UpdateCRM() inside a loop, it is getting time out after updating some record.
Is there any better to solve the problem.

Here is my UpdateCRM() method.

```
function UpdateCRM()
{
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;
//Convert object to JSON
sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(emailSendoutList);

httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigUtility.crmUpdateServiceURL + "/UpdateCrmAfterEMailed");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.Timeout = 600000;
httpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 600000;
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = sJSON.Length;

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
streamWriter.Write(sJSON);
streamWriter.Flush();
streamWriter.Close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close to object after using it.

try adding this after using streamwriter.

```
httpWebRequest.abort();
```

EDIT:

Try like this, maybe it response is causing the problem?

```
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(Response.GetRequestStream()))
{
streamWriter.Write(sJSON);
streamWriter.Flush();
streamWriter.Close();
}
Response.Close();
```

Comment: I have added code.
    finally{
    httpWebRequest.Abort();
    httpWebRequest = null;
    }

Comment: Have you tried declaring a response object you can later close after reading into a streamwriter?

Comment: Yes, after closing the response is little bit faster.

Comment: No, still getting timeout but little bit faster. Thanks for your answer.